# Xcode showing different view controllers based on a condition

Tags: swift, xcode

I am new to Xcode/swift and my problem right now would be showing 2 different view controllers.
For example, when I choose negative from a pickerview and press a next button, another form would come up. However, if I choose positive, when I press the next button it will show a successfully booked view controller. How can I do this? Should I use let else ? In my storyboard, do I create 2 view controllers with different segues as well?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You should check if the chosen one is positive or not and then perform the correct segue. It all just goes down to which segue you will perform.

```
if (isNegativeChosen) {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "showView1", sender: self)
} else {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "showView2", sender: self)
}
```

In storyboard you have to set up the two segues going out from this view controller to the two new ones and have 'showView1' and 'showView2' as their names set accordingly.